# Can't access contents of NSArray on JSON Framework for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I can successfully parse the contents of a JSON file, using the JSON-Framework 3.0, but I'm not being able to extract all elements of the NSArray.

**The app crashes at this line** (shown below) `link = [myJsonArray objectAtIndex:0];` **giving me this message on the console:**  `-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x70ea20`.

Here is my code:

```
NSError *error;
NSString *link;
NSArray *myJsonArray;

NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myJSONfile" ofType:@"json"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
myJsonArray = [[parser objectWithString:jsonString error:&error] copy];
[parser release];

link = [myJsonArray objectAtIndex:0]; 

NSLog(@"json returns: %@", myJsonArray);
```

And here is my JSON file:

```
{
   "Programs": [
      {"link1": "http://www.myWebSite1.aspx",
       "program name": "Live Show at 9",
       "speaker": "Dr. Speaker 1"},
      {"link2": "http://www.myWebSite2.aspx",
       "name": "Dr. Speaker 2",
       "speaker": "Live Show at 10"}
   ]
}
```

This is the Log Output:

```
 JSON Output: {

  Programs =     (
      {
       link1: "http://www.myWebSite1.aspx",
       program name: "Live Show at 9",
       speaker: "Dr. Speaker 1"},

     {link2: "http://www.myWebSite2.aspx",
      program name: "Dr. Speaker 2",
      speaker: "Live Show at 10"}
 );
}
```

What Am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the link1 value you should use:

```
[[[myJsonArray objectForKey:@"Programs"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"link1"]
```

Comment: Maybe because you are logging the whole object. Try NSLog(@"link1:%@",[[[myJsonArray objectForKey:@"Programs"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"link1"])

Comment: Now I got it right! Though I received this warning:  Semantic Issue: 'NSArray' may not respond to 'objectForKey:' Any Idea why? Thanks!

Comment: Beacuse you declared myJsonArray as an NSArray*. Declare it as an NSdictionary*, as you are using it. You can also declare it as id for better understanding. Remember: declaring a variable with a type does not imply it's an instance of that type.

Comment: Also, you must get the difference between compile-time (the warning) and run-time (the crash)

Comment: I changed it and the warning is gone. Thanks for pointing that out. Today I've learned so much with you all !!!!

Answer (score 2):

Your object is a dictionary.  An array can be returned by accessing

```
NSArray *aLinkArray = [myJasonArray valueForKey:@"Programs"]
```

Comment: With this line of code the console shows me each element of the array as a group, showing: link1, program name and speaker. How do I separate each one of them (link1, program and speaker) in separate NSStrings?

Comment: [[aLinkArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"link1"]

Answer (score 1):

You are sending objectAtIndex: to a NSDictionary which is wrong. Just try printing what you are assigning to myJsonArray and see if it is a valid array in the first place.

Comment: Yes, the myJsonArray is a valid array and I can see all its elements printed out on the console using NSLog(@"json returns: %@", myJsonArray);

Comment: No, myJsonArray is a NSDictionary, as the console and everybody here is telling to you. You can check calling isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]

Comment: I did, and yes, you guys are totally right. Thanks for pointing that out. Today I've learned so much with you all !!!!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the text in your JSON file starts with `[` and ends with `]`. In this case, `objectWithString:` should return an array.

Right now, it seems, it is returning an `NSDictionary` which would be the case if your file starts with `{` and ends with `}`.

Comment: I have [... and the beginning for my JSON file, and ...] and the end. Inside, the elements have {...}. I tried to change the [...] for {...} and the NSArray returns NULL.

Answer (score 1):

The parser returns a NSDictionary and not an NSArray in your case.

Add a

```
NSLog(@"json returns: %@", myJsonArray);
```

before accessing that object and see the results in the console.

Comment: I see all elements of the JSON file with NSLog(@"json returns: %@", myJsonArray); I just can't separate them all into individual NSStrings.

Comment: Please try to post the most relevant parts of that log-output and of the original JSON file into your question.

Answer (score -1):

You most likely have invalid JSON. Try pasting your JSON text into http://jsonlint.com/ and see if it is valid.

Comment: The OP stated in his comments that he/she gets a proper output from the logging -> the JSON is valid or SBJSON would have failed to parse it entirely.

Comment: I thought it was improbable to be correct JSON if he can just exchange `[]` for `{}` without getting a JSON error. I do not know how 3rd party parsers react to faulty JSON, could be silently ignored. It might look correct if output on the console...